# Can't access RDS database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have brand new RDS postgresql database with the followint endpoint:
`<databaseID>.<id>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

and it has the following under security :

`VPC security groups
default (sg-zzzzzzzz)
( active )`

That security group has inbound rules:

`PostgreSQL | TCP | 5432 | 0.0.0.0/0
PostgreSQL | TCP | 5432 | ::/0`

When I try :
`nc -zv <databaseID>.<id>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432`
It waits about a minute and gives me :
`nc: connectx to <databaseID>.<id>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port 5432 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out`

If I try this:

`psql \
--host=<databaseID>.<id>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com \                                              --port=5432 \                                                                                                          --username=tazmanianDevil \                                                                                                       --password \                                                                                       --dbname=mydbname`

I get prompted for a password, I enter it, and then, after about a minute, I get :

`psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out                                                    Is the server running on host "<databaseID>.<id>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (12.34.56.78) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Everything I've seen has pointed at security rules as the problem but I'm pretty sure mine are OK.  What else could it be?

Comment: Typically, if an error takes a while to return, this indicates that your computer was unable to connect to the remote machine and the attempt timed-out. This is normally due to Security Group settings, but yours seems okay. If the error returns immediately, then it means that you successfully connected to the server but the connection was rejected.

Comment: Also worth noting is that `Public accessibility` is set to `yes`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my route table was pointing to a defunct internet gateway.  The status was listed as `blackhole`.  So I just had to point it to my real IG and now it works.  :D